# Installing Postgis on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk using config file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postgis, geodjango

I'm trying to install postigs on my beanstalk instance but I can't find a working approach.
My very first one, was to install it via apt packages, but I realized that they are not supported by the EBS EC2 Linux instance, so I tried by combining wget + install, but the problem in this case is that I get I timeout error, since the commands are slow to execute…
so i tried to download the sources using the appropriate configuration and to use shell commands only to build them… but I still getting a timeout exception.
My latest config is:

```
packages:
  yum:
    python-devel: []
    libpcap: []
    libpcap-devel: []
    libnet: []
    libnet-devel: []
    pcre: []
    pcre-devel: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    automake: []
    autoconf: []
    libtool: []
    make: []
    libyaml: []
    libyaml-devel: []
    libxml2: []
    libxml2-devel: []
    zlib: []
    zlib-devel: []
    file-devel: []
    postgresql: []
    postgresql-devel: []
    postgresql-contrib: []
    geoip: []
    geoip-devel: []
    graphviz: []
    graphviz-devel: []
    binutils: []

sources:
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-4.8.0.zip
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.4.2.tar.bz2
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.10.1/gdal1101.zip
  /home/ec2-user: http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.1.tar.gz

commands:
  01_enable_root_access:
    command: test -e sudo-patched.txt || echo Defaults:root \!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers && echo 'yes' > sudo-patched.txt
  02_install_proj:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/proj-4.8.0
    command: test -e proj-check.txt || ./configure && make && sudo make install && echo 'ok' > proj-check.txt
  03_install_geos:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/geos-3.4.2
    command: test -e geos-check.txt || ./configure && make && sudo make install && echo 'ok' > geos-check.txt
  04_install_gdal:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/gdal-1.10.1
    command: test -e gdal-check.txt || ./configure --with-python=yes && make && sudo make install && echo 'ok' > gdal-check.txt
  05_install_postgis:
    cwd: /home/ec2-user/postgis-2.1.1
    command: test -e postgis-check.txt || ./configure && make && sudo make install && echo 'ok' > postgis-check.txt
```

I'm lost… I spent 3 days for nothing… and I'm stuck, my project is based on GeoDjango and I must find a way to install its dependencies. Is there a way to have that libraries on the EBS instance without to have to create a custom AMI? (I don't like the idea of the custom AMI, since I would loose the benefits of EBS updates and "automagics")
(I'm using a micro type instance with Linux 64bit and python 2.7)

Comment: Try increasing the size of the instance.  Compiling a package seems like an awful lot to do during startup.  Can you post logs ?

Comment: I gave up, now I created a customized ami… it's impossible to install all that stuff by using config files, it needs ~1 hour to install and compile proj + geos + gdal + postgis :P